How to load a plugin locally without LazyVim
was having some issues loading a plugin using LazyVim so im trying to load it locally in my computer and access it from there.
the plugin in the repo was not compiled and the LazyVim timed out when compiling it.
i com[iled it and is in my local pc in desktop in a folder
How do i use Lazy to access the locally compiled file now?
using chatgpt i found out i should do something like:
return {
  dir = "path"
}

but it doesnt seem to work.
im on windows and putting the path doesnt seem to work. maybe because the formatting is wrong?
some formats ive tried:
"C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\Desktop\\FOLDER\\folder"
/home/desktop/FOLDER/folder

how do i manage my lazyVim plugin to make it run properly and load things from my local PC
  ~\appdata\local\nvim (copy)
   lua (copy)
     config (copy)
   │ │  cornelis.lua (copy)
   │ │  hmm.lua (copy)
   │ │  lazy.lua (copy)
   │ │  mason.lua (copy)
   │ └  remap.lua (copy)
     plugins (copy)
     │  auto_pair.lua (copy)
     │  bufferLine.lua (copy)
     │  colorscheme.lua (copy)
     │  editor.lua (copy)
     │  lsp-config.lua (copy)
     │  lua_line.lua (copy)
     │  neotree.lua (copy)
     │  noice.lua (copy)
     │  nvim_cmp.lua (copy)
     │  spec1.lua (copy)
     │  telescope.lua (copy)
     │  treesitter.lua (copy)
     │  ui.lua (copy)
     └  vimBeGood.lua (copy)
    init.lua (copy)
    lazy-lock.json (copy)
    lazyvim.json

this is my config so far and i want to stick to this config unless absolutelty no other solution is left
